# how to add delay between two actions

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I wanted te delay the interstitial with 1 second after clicking on a button.
I used Thread.sleep() but it didnt work coz the message that it must be shown after clicking the button is also delayef.
I want to click on the button and wait the message 1 secobd then show the ad.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        showMessage();
        ...
      }
    }, ms);
```

That will delay the operations in `run()` for the specified `ms` in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Handler with postDelay. pass duration in milliseconds then run() will call after given duration.

```
             Handler h = new Handler();
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // code that will run after 1 second(1000 ms)
                    }
                };
                h.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```